# node peer dependency error with mongodb

Tags: node.js, git, bash, mongodb

Don't know how to get it to work after getting a long string of errors in the window. What else do I need to install or do? (using windows 10)

The error after typing npm install in git bash:

> npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency mongodb@~1.4 included from mongoskin 
>   npm WARN peerDependencies will no longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
>
> kerberos@0.0.11 install C:\Users\Desktop\nodeblog\node_modules\monk\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos
>   (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "nodeblog",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "1.13.x",
    "connect-flash": "latest",
    "cookie-parser": "1.3.x",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "4.13.x",
    "express-messages": "latest",
    "express-session": "latest",
    "express-validator": "latest",
    "jade": "1.9.x",
    "moment": "latest",
    "mongodb": "latest",
    "monk": "latest",
    "morgan": "1.5.x",
    "multer": "latest",
    "serve-favicon": "2.3.x"
  }
}
```

Comment: what versions of node, node-gyp and npm do you use?

Comment: The 'error' you've pasted in is actually a warning letting you know that it has installed `mongodb@~1.4` this time but future versions of npm will no longer do so. You will have to add it to your package.json yourself if you start using npm v3+. If that's the only issue in the output, then your install probably worked ok. Does your app run?

Comment: Thanks yeah just realised it still works fine despite the string of warnings. Will comment if there are further issues